# When I try to put my div to position:absolute; all elements below go nuts

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation menu and upon hovering, I wanted my dropdown to display below the header. I set my position to the header relative so that my dropdown lists will be positioned to absolute but what actually happened is that the elements below my header was affected too and I honestly don't know what is happening with my code.

I'll have to provide a sample over here:

```
<div id ="lower-header">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="images/logo/logo_01.png">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">KU 스타트업</a>
                    <div class="sub-menu-whole">

                    </div>
            </li>
            <li>프로그램</li>
            <li>스타트업 리더</li>
            <li>창업보육</li>
            <li>창업멘토단</li>
            <li>커뮤니티</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/alexdeveloperdeneris/pen/wNoMjm

it includes the code snippets from my css and html

[image: this is what happens with my header. i took out the overflow hidden in my #lower-header]

Comment: your codepen is not working for me

Comment: Even i was not able to replicate it.. please add a proper working link or add a code snippet. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to recreate your issue (you should switch from SASS to SCSS on your codepen by the way).

However, in general its important to know how `position: absolute` and `position: relative` affect the element you are styling.

[This article](https://www.lifewire.com/absolute-vs-relative-3466208) does a good job of explaining it but what I'm guessing is your issue and what is important to know is that when you add `position: absolute` to an element, you are removing it from the normal flow of the document and instead placing it somewhere precisely on the page. `position: relative` operates in a similar way but does **not** remove the element from document flow. Thus the two can have big effects on the elements around them.